# Why can I omit the subsequent null-conditional operators in an invocation chain?

Tags: c#, null-conditional-operator

Consider the following code:

```
IEnumerable<int> xx = null;
var tt = xx?.Where(x => x > 2).Select(x => x.ToString());
```

It assigns `null` to `tt`.
The question is: why does it work properly?

I thought I must use `?.` before Select as `?.Where(...)` returns `null`.
Besides, if I split the second line into two separate lines:

```
IEnumerable<int> xx = null;
var yy = xx?.Where(x => x > 2);
var zz = yy.Select(x => x.ToString());
```

There will be the `ArgumentNullException` on the third line as `yy == null`.

What's the magic? :)
If this is because of short-circuiting, I've never thought that it can act like this.

Comment: `WHERE` doesn't return null - it will return empty `IEnumerable<T>` - so it can't be null. You might have been thinking about `FirstOrDefault()`

Comment: @VidmantasBlazevicius `Where` *isn't even invoked*.

Comment: @VidmantasBlazevicius Why doesn't? `yy` in the second block is null.

Comment: `Where` doesn't get called because `xx` is null.

Comment: You're second bit of code would be equivalent to `var tt = (xx?.Where(x => x > 2)).Select(x => x.ToString())`

Comment: @juharr Yes, I know, and there's no wonder there, as for the first example.

Comment: Even this works: `xx?.Where(x => x > 2).Select(x => x.ToString()).First().Length.GetHashCode();`

Comment: The accepted answer is correct, but if this weren't the case (hypothetically) they could still have implemented the extension methods to accept and return null instead of throwing an exception. In that case, your second example would also have worked.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, this is due to short-circuiting.  From the [MSDN reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators):

> ...[T]he null-condition operators are short-circuiting. If one operation in a chain of conditional member access and index operation returns null, then the rest of the chain’s execution stops.

The reason your second example throws is because you have separate unchained statements.  Short-circuiting cannot be applied across multiple statements.

Comment: Technically, that cannot be an explanation. I have the chain of one conditional member acces and one -- unconditional. No chain of conditional member access, as in the docs.

Comment: MSDN isn't as explicit as it could be, but that *is* the explanation.  Any other chained operations with the same precedence are ignored, whether they use the conditional or not.  In the next sentence, MSDN clarifies that only operations with a *lower precedence* will continue to execute.

Comment: Okay, I agree with this, especially with addition of your clarification. Thank you.

Comment: So we can omit conditional (use just subsequent unconditional operators) unless we get the may-be-null output from non-null input, right?

Comment: Yes (provided I'm understanding you correctly).  Once you've gotten past the thing-that-might-be-null, all of the subsequent operators can be non-conditional until/unless you reach another thing-that-might-be-null.

Comment: Yes, I meant just that. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

The *null-conditional operator* or also known as the *null propagation operator* is *short-circuiting* i.e if one operation in the chain:

```
var tt = xx?.Where(x => x > 2).Select(x => x.ToString());
```

returns `null`, then the rest of the chain’s execution stops.

So in the above example `Where` is never invoked as `xx` is `null`.

As for the second example, you're getting an `ArgumentNullException`
because that's the behaviour of extension methods. in this specific case, the `Select` throws a `ArgumentNullException` when the *source* or the provided *selector* is `null`.

Comment: "then the rest of the chain’s execution stops." Whatever further is in the chain, conditionals or not.

Comment: BJ Myers has already provided a link to the MSDN page that explains this in detail. So my answer is pretty much stating the documentation.